# What is the simplest 3D file format to parse?

Tags: 3d

I want to parse Blender-Made Files directly into my homemade Lisp program. I've been pulling data out of .X3D files manually. Is this the best format to focus on writing a parser for?

Thanks!

Comment: Get a LISP library which will do it for You.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Write an exporter.
No, really.

That way you can output exactly the data you need in the format you want.

When you start from one of the existing plugins, it's actually quite easy.

Comment: I would have never thought of that! I could dump it into lisp code directly and skip the middleman. Also, great example of answering my need, instead of just the question.

Answer (score 5):

I've always found OBJ files easiest to parse, but they tend to be large because they're "human readable."  However, they're public and standardized.

If you need it, the Obj Specification:

http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/

Answer (score 1):

Milkshape (MS3D) format was quite easy to implement a reader for, in C++ and C#. Here's the spec I used (retrieved from [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20120206055629/http://chumbalum.swissquake.ch/ms3d/ms3dspec.txt)):

```
//
//
//
//                MilkShape 3D 1.8.2 File Format Specification
//
//
//                  This specifcation is written in C style.
//
//
// The data structures are defined in the order as they appear in the .ms3d file.
//
//
//
//
//



//
// max values
//
#define MAX_VERTICES    65534
#define MAX_TRIANGLES   65534
#define MAX_GROUPS      255
#define MAX_MATERIALS   128
#define MAX_JOINTS      128



//
// flags
//
#define SELECTED        1
#define HIDDEN          2
#define SELECTED2       4
#define DIRTY           8



//
// types
//
#ifndef byte
typedef unsigned char byte;
#endif // byte

#ifndef word
typedef unsigned short word;
#endif // word


// force one byte alignment
#include <pshpack1.h>

//
// First comes the header (sizeof(ms3d_header_t) == 14)
//
typedef struct
{
    char    id[10];                                     // always "MS3D000000"
    int     version;                                    // 4
} ms3d_header_t;

//
// Then comes the number of vertices
//
word nNumVertices; // 2 bytes

//
// Then come nNumVertices times ms3d_vertex_t structs (sizeof(ms3d_vertex_t) == 15)
//
typedef struct
{
    byte    flags;                                      // SELECTED | SELECTED2 | HIDDEN
    float   vertex[3];                                  //
    char    boneId;                                     // -1 = no bone
    byte    referenceCount;
} ms3d_vertex_t;

//
// Then comes the number of triangles
//
word nNumTriangles; // 2 bytes

//
// Then come nNumTriangles times ms3d_triangle_t structs (sizeof(ms3d_triangle_t) == 70)
//
typedef struct
{
    word    flags;                                      // SELECTED | SELECTED2 | HIDDEN
    word    vertexIndices[3];                           //
    float   vertexNormals[3][3];                        //
    float   s[3];                                       //
    float   t[3];                                       //
    byte    smoothingGroup;                             // 1 - 32
    byte    groupIndex;                                 //
} ms3d_triangle_t;

//
// Then comes the number of groups
//
word nNumGroups; // 2 bytes

//
// Then come nNumGroups times groups (the sizeof a group is dynamic, because of triangleIndices is numtriangles long)
//
typedef struct
{
    byte            flags;                              // SELECTED | HIDDEN
    char            name[32];                           //
    word            numtriangles;                       //
    word            triangleIndices[numtriangles];      // the groups group the triangles
    char            materialIndex;                      // -1 = no material
} ms3d_group_t;

//
// number of materials
//
word nNumMaterials; // 2 bytes

//
// Then come nNumMaterials times ms3d_material_t structs (sizeof(ms3d_material_t) == 361)
//
typedef struct
{
    char            name[32];                           //
    float           ambient[4];                         //
    float           diffuse[4];                         //
    float           specular[4];                        //
    float           emissive[4];                        //
    float           shininess;                          // 0.0f - 128.0f
    float           transparency;                       // 0.0f - 1.0f
    char            mode;                               // 0, 1, 2 is unused now
    char            texture[128];                        // texture.bmp
    char            alphamap[128];                       // alpha.bmp
} ms3d_material_t;

//
// save some keyframer data
//
float fAnimationFPS; // 4 bytes
float fCurrentTime; // 4 bytes
int iTotalFrames; // 4 bytes

//
// number of joints
//
word nNumJoints; // 2 bytes

//
// Then come nNumJoints joints (the size of joints are dynamic, because each joint has a differnt count of keys
//
typedef struct // 16 bytes
{
    float           time;                               // time in seconds
    float           rotation[3];                        // x, y, z angles
} ms3d_keyframe_rot_t;

typedef struct // 16 bytes
{
    float           time;                               // time in seconds
    float           position[3];                        // local position
} ms3d_keyframe_pos_t;

typedef struct
{
    byte            flags;                              // SELECTED | DIRTY
    char            name[32];                           //
    char            parentName[32];                     //
    float           rotation[3];                        // local reference matrix
    float           position[3];

    word            numKeyFramesRot;                    //
    word            numKeyFramesTrans;                  //

    ms3d_keyframe_rot_t keyFramesRot[numKeyFramesRot];      // local animation matrices
    ms3d_keyframe_pos_t keyFramesTrans[numKeyFramesTrans];  // local animation matrices
} ms3d_joint_t;

//
// Then comes the subVersion of the comments part, which is not available in older files
//
int subVersion; // subVersion is = 1, 4 bytes

// Then comes the numer of group comments
unsigned int nNumGroupComments; // 4 bytes

//
// Then come nNumGroupComments times group comments, which are dynamic, because the comment can be any length
//
typedef struct
{
  int index;                                            // index of group, material or joint
  int commentLength;                                    // length of comment (terminating '\0' is not saved), "MC" has comment length of 2 (not 3)
  char comment[commentLength];                      // comment
} ms3d_comment_t;

// Then comes the number of material comments
int nNumMaterialComments; // 4 bytes

//
// Then come nNumMaterialComments times material comments, which are dynamic, because the comment can be any length
//

// Then comes the number of joint comments
int nNumJointComments; // 4 bytes

//
// Then come nNumJointComments times joint comments, which are dynamic, because the comment can be any length
//

// Then comes the number of model comments, which is always 0 or 1
int nHasModelComment; // 4 bytes

//
// Then come nHasModelComment times model comments, which are dynamic, because the comment can be any length
//


// Then comes the subversion of the vertex extra information like bone weights, extra etc.
int subVersion;     // subVersion is = 2, 4 bytes

// ms3d_vertex_ex_t for subVersion == 1
typedef struct
{
  char boneIds[3];                                  // index of joint or -1, if -1, then that weight is ignored, since subVersion 1
  byte weights[3];                                  // vertex weight ranging from 0 - 255, last weight is computed by 1.0 - sum(all weights), since subVersion 1
  // weight[0] is the weight for boneId in ms3d_vertex_t
  // weight[1] is the weight for boneIds[0]
  // weight[2] is the weight for boneIds[1]
  // 1.0f - weight[0] - weight[1] - weight[2] is the weight for boneIds[2]
} ms3d_vertex_ex_t;

// ms3d_vertex_ex_t for subVersion == 2
typedef struct
{
  char boneIds[3];                                  // index of joint or -1, if -1, then that weight is ignored, since subVersion 1
  byte weights[3];                                  // vertex weight ranging from 0 - 100, last weight is computed by 1.0 - sum(all weights), since subVersion 1
  // weight[0] is the weight for boneId in ms3d_vertex_t
  // weight[1] is the weight for boneIds[0]
  // weight[2] is the weight for boneIds[1]
  // 1.0f - weight[0] - weight[1] - weight[2] is the weight for boneIds[2]
  unsigned int extra;                                   // vertex extra, which can be used as color or anything else, since subVersion 2
} ms3d_vertex_ex_t;

// Then comes nNumVertices times ms3d_vertex_ex_t structs (sizeof(ms3d_vertex_ex_t) == 10)

// Then comes the subversion of the joint extra information like color etc.
int subVersion;     // subVersion is = 2, 4 bytes

// ms3d_joint_ex_t for subVersion == 1
typedef struct
{
  float color[3];   // joint color, since subVersion == 1
} ms3d_joint_ex_t;

// Then comes nNumJoints times ms3d_joint_ex_t structs (sizeof(ms3d_joint_ex_t) == 12)

// Then comes the subversion of the model extra information
int subVersion;     // subVersion is = 1, 4 bytes

// ms3d_model_ex_t for subVersion == 1
typedef struct
{
  float jointSize;  // joint size, since subVersion == 1
  int transparencyMode; // 0 = simple, 1 = depth buffered with alpha ref, 2 = depth sorted triangles, since subVersion == 1
  float alphaRef; // alpha reference value for transparencyMode = 1, since subVersion == 1
} ms3d_model_ex_t;

#include <poppack.h>


//
// Mesh Transformation:
// 
// 0. Build the transformation matrices from the rotation and position
// 1. Multiply the vertices by the inverse of local reference matrix (lmatrix0)
// 2. then translate the result by (lmatrix0 * keyFramesTrans)
// 3. then multiply the result by (lmatrix0 * keyFramesRot)
//
// For normals skip step 2.
//
//
//
// NOTE:  this file format may change in future versions!
//
//
// - Mete Ciragan
//
```

Answer (score 1):

The .obj is of course the easiest to to parse, but if you need something a little more powerful (with animations) then get the .md2 file format.

[link text](http://tfc.duke.free.fr/coding/md2-specs-en.html)

If I can dig up some of my code from high school I might be able to find a md2 loader I wrote.

Comment: I think a custom blender exporter will get items into my code faster. I appreciate offer for your code however.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest to load is OBJ (which is human readable), others are horribly complex.